# Possible to pass env vars into chpst without envdir?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, daemon, daemontools, runit

I use runit to daemonize my web application, and I'm trying to see if I can have my process managed by `sv` not have to have a corresponding `envdir` for its environment variables. I wonder if I can just pass those vars directly into my call to `chpst`. This is the `run` file under `/etc/service/myapp`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
cd /var/www/myapp
# what it currently looks like
exec chpst -u www-data:www-data /var/www/myapp/myapp
# what I'd ideally like to be able to do
FOO=bar BAZ=qux exec chpst -u www-data:www-data /var/www/myapp/myapp
```

As I mentioned, `chpst` also comes with a `-e` option to pass a directly with environment variables to it, I could use that, but I'm trying to avoid it for simplicity (fewer things to maintain). Is that at all possible? Tips?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you literally *can* do exactly what you wish to ideally be able to do. For example, `FOO=bar exec printenv FOO` in a `#!/bin/sh -` script should print "bar". If you have any shell where that doesn't work right I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass environments using the 'env' argument right before you invoke your app. I've done this for a single environment, though I'm not sure how one would provide multiple envariables

```
exec chpst -u www-data:www-data env LOGNAME='www-data' /var/www/myapp/myapp
```

Comment: For setting multiple environment variables when launching an application with `env`, just use `env VAR1=value VAR2=value VAR3=value application`.

Comment: To be clear, `env` is not a special argument to `chpst`, it's a separate program. Both `env` and `chpst` are "exec chaining" programs - they change something about the process, and then execute the next program (the rest of their arguments) within the same process. So you could do `env` before `chpst` if you wanted, and more importantly, you can't have other options intended for `chpst` after the `env` argument to it.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* just do:

```bsh
FOO=bar BAZ=qux exec chpst -u www-data:www-data /var/www/myapp/myapp
```

If someone knows of a `/bin/sh` where this doesn't work I'd love to hear about it, but this line that you wished to be able to do would work exactly as you wished it to work on every shell I've tried it on.